# Unable to solve univariate function using Apache Commons Math library

Tags: java, function, math

I'm using the `Apache Commons Math Library 3.4`. I have implemented an univariate function name `PFunction`. In my Main class, I tried to solve for `2 * p * Math.log(p) / (p + 1) -w`, where `w` is `-0.5`.

However, I get an error of:

```
org.apache.commons.math3.exception.NoBracketingException: function values at endpoints do not have different signs, endpoints: [1, 1,000], values: [0.5, 14.302]
    at org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.solvers.BrentSolver.doSolve(BrentSolver.java:122)
    at org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.solvers.BaseAbstractUnivariateSolver.solve(BaseAbstractUnivariateSolver.java:195)
    at org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.solvers.BaseAbstractUnivariateSolver.solve(BaseAbstractUnivariateSolver.java:200)
    at Main.main(Main.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

I have tried other solvers, e.g. Muller's Method, and they show the same error. Also, I found that a positive value of w, e.g 0.5, do not give me an error. Thanks for your help.

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.UnivariateFunction;

public class PFunction implements  UnivariateFunction {
    private double w;

    public PFunction(double w) {
        this.w = w;
    }

    @Override
    public double value(double p) {
        return 2 * p * Math.log(p) / (p + 1) -w;
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.UnivariateFunction;
import org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.solvers.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double p;
        UnivariateFunction univariateFunction = new PFunction(-0.5);
        BrentSolver brentSolver = new BrentSolver();

        try {
            p = brentSolver.solve(1000, univariateFunction, 1, 1000);
            System.out.println("Brent solver, p: " + p);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with this but the error seems clear. Your function values have the same sign on both sides of the interval, and so are not bracketed. Try using a subclass of [AbstractUnivariateSolver](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/analysis/solvers/AbstractUnivariateSolver.html) that doesn't require bracketing.